# Why is eclipse highlighting R.id.tabhost?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm trying to implement a tabs into my app, but id tabhost is being highlighted, why?

Every tutorial I look at has *TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost)*, and everytime I include this line id tabhost is hightlighted, with error: **tabhost cannot be resolved or is not a field**.

**recipe_list.java:**

```
    TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

tabs.setup();

TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec.setIndicator("Clock");
tabs.addTab(spec);

spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
spec.setIndicator("Button");
tabs.addTab(spec);
```

---

**recipe_list.xml**, I have list views in every tab:

```
   <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

**or**

```
TabHost tabs=getTabHost();
```

Comment: works thanks ill accept your answer in 11 minutes - thats what stackoverflow tells me